# Complex Analysis: Showing $z^\alpha w^\alpha \neq (zw)^\alpha$ When Choosing the Principle Branch

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am to come up with a case where $z^\alpha w^\alpha \neq (zw)^\alpha$ where $z,w,\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$

We know that: $z^\alpha w^\alpha = e^{\alpha \ln(z)}e^{\alpha \ln(w)}$ 
 and $(zw)^\alpha = e^{\alpha \ln(zw)} = e^{\alpha(\ln(z) + \ln(w))} = e^{\alpha \ln(z)} e^{\alpha \ln(w)} = z^\alpha w^\alpha$

But here I have shown that they are both equal. Does there exist a case where they don't equal each other?

Comment: "But here I have shown that they are both equal" Actually you have shown nothing of the sort since you assumed (and used) that $\log(zw)=\log(z)+\log(w)$, which does not always hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, $z^\alpha = \exp(\alpha \log(z))$ where $\log(z)$ is any branch of the logarithm of $z$.  The principal (not principle) branch is the one with imaginary part between $-\pi$ and $\pi$.
Now

$$ z^{\alpha} w^{\alpha} = \exp(\alpha \log(z) + \alpha \log(w)) $$

$$ (z w)^\alpha = \exp(\alpha \log(z w))$$

so to make these unequal, you'll want a case where (using the principal branches) $\log(zw) \ne \log(z) + \log(w)$.  That must be true when 
$\text{Im}(\log(z)) + \text{Im}(\log(w))$ is not in the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$.  Thus for example, try $z = w = e^{3 \pi i/4}$: $\log(z) = \log(w) = 3 \pi i/4$, but $\log(zw)$ can't be $3 \pi i/2$ and must instead be $3 \pi i/2 - 2 \pi i = -\pi i/2$.  And then you'll find
$$z^\alpha w^\alpha = e^{3 \pi i \alpha/2}$$
while $$(zw)^\alpha = e^{-\pi i \alpha/2}$$
and these are not the same unless $\alpha$ is an integer.

Comment: Sorry I'm still a bit confused, we know that $log(z) + log(w) = 3\pi /2$, and that it is not in the Principal branch. But why does $log(zw) \neq 3\pi/2$ ?

Comment: $zw = e^{3 \pi i/2}$, so $\log(zw) = 3 \pi i/2 + 2 \pi i n$ for some integer $n$.  But if $\log$ means the principal branch of the logarithm, the imaginary part has to be between $-\pi$ and $\pi$.  So it must be $-\pi i/2$, because that's the only possibility with imaginary part in that interval.